# X10 reading from a file not as expected

Tags: x10-language

I encountered following behavior when reading from a text file.

```
val input = new File(inputFileName);
val inp = input.openRead();
Console.OUT.println(inp.lines().next());
if (inp.lines().hasNext())
     Console.OUT.println(inp.lines().next());
```

---

my input file contains

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
```

---

As a result I get

```
0 1
0 3
```

It seems that `inp.lines().hasNext()` has moved the pointer forward and as a result one line is skipped in the text file. 
Is this a bug?

Comment: Welcome to the world of parallel programming. Head first.

Comment: thanks I guess.. though this put me down, I'm actually having a while loop instead of if, now I need to think of another termination criteria :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this looks like a bug.  `x10.io.FileReader.lines().hasNext()` should not be skipping forward in the text file.
Could you please raise an issue in the [X10 JIRA project](https://xtenlang.atlassian.net/projects/XTENLANG/issues)?

Comment: Thanks, I have submitted a defect